# Add submenu items to Orchard CMS Admin Menu

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have several blogs on my Orchard site and I wanted to list them under `Blog` in the Admin Menu. In the blog management page I can select `Show on admin menu` and use the `Position` field to place it.

What I want to do is add my blogs to be nested under `Blog`. I attempted to use 3.1 etc but my blogs just appear at the first level in the admin menu. This will be confusing for my users who need to simply add blog posts.

Comment: You can't, sorry, not without writing code.

Comment: Ah, well I can write code - I assumed I was doing something wrong!

Comment: Ah cool, then you can implement a menu provider that adds menu entries for each blog under the general blog entry. You can take a look at this for inspiration, it does something very similar: https://vandelay.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Menus/ContentAdminMenu.cs

Comment: I actually find it quite strange that you can't customize the admin menu through a UI!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by Bertrand Le Roy, this is not possible by configuration only. One must write a module to add menu items in this manner.